# What is the quality in flutter_image_compress

Tags: flutter, image-compression

I found that the quality compress by flutter_image_compress is not based on percentage. For example like 4.58MB image after compress with quality 50 is return 590KB. Is that mean the quality is not precentage ?

Reference : https://jtmuller5-98869.medium.com/image-compression-in-flutter-e0585ce960cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `quality` is not a percentage. It's passed through to the underlying JPEG compressor, so you have to look at how that underlying compressor interprets it. But even that might not be well-documented.

For example, on iOS, [the implementation](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_image_compress/blob/master/ios/Classes/CompressHandler.m) divides `quality` by 100 to convert it to a number in the range 0.0 to 1.0 and uses the resulting fraction as the [`kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagedestinationlossycompressionquality) parameter. Apple documents that parameter as follows:

> The desired compression quality to use when writing to an image destination. If present, the value associated with this key must be a `CFNumberRef` data type in the range `0.0` to `1.0`. A value of `1.0` specifies to use lossless compression if destination format supports it. A value of `0.0` implies to use maximum compression.

You might also want to read the [JPEG image compression FAQ answer about quality](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-5.html).